# C# cookies in javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, cookies

I'm using an  to call a javascript function, like so:

```
<a onClick="AddCookie();">Click Here</a>
```

This is my javascript function, very basic:

```
function AddCookie(){
    Alert ("test"):
}
```

Whenever the user clicks on "Click Here" I want a cookie created, now I am using ASP in Umbraco which means I can use C# code through HTML so I am creating a cookie like this:

```
HttpCookie IsDesktopCookie = new HttpCookie("IsDesktopVersion");
IsDesktopCookie.Value = "true";
IsDesktopCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(IsDesktopCookie);
```

Adding that to my function:

```
function AddCookie(){
     alert("test");

    HttpCookie IsDesktopCookie = new HttpCookie("IsDesktopVersion");
    IsDesktopCookie.Value = "true";
    IsDesktopCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(IsDesktopCookie);
}
```

However that doesn't work! I also tried adding <% %> around the C# code but it seems to break every time saying function "AddCookie" is not defined.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: You should read a basic ASP.NET tutorial. You cannot execute **server-side** code in a **client-side** function. You need to either do a postback or use something like AJAX for that call if you want to do it on the server. Otherwise, just use JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can write C# Razor code inside a html page (or rather a cshtml page), you cannot execute C# in the browser just in the same way that you can't execute PHP in the browser even though you can use it within your html pages (or rather .php pages).

Any C# you write within your html template will be executed by the server when the request is made. You cannot interchangeably put C# in a javascript function and expect it to compile to javascript.

If you want to create a cookie on a button click, you can do so with javascript entirely:

```
function addCookie() {
    document.cookie = "name=mycookie; expires=Fri, 23 Feb 2018 09:45:00 UTC; path=/";
}
```

You're then free to retrieve that cookie via javascript or use your C# code to check for the cookie at request time and render your page content differently on page load if that's what you're hoping to do.

Answer (score -1):

```
function AddCookie()
{
    alert("test");
    $.post(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateCookie")',
        success: function(result)
        {
            //cokiee created
        },
        complete: function() {}
    });
```

You can create or edit cookie like that. In 'CreateCookie' action, write your cookie creation codes

Answer (score -1):

If you need to create cookie in your javascript code then I will suggest you to look at jquery library 
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

In which you can easily create a cookie

```
$.cookie('name', 'value');
```

To read cookie value

```
$.cookie('name');
```

Comment: Yeah I'll go with creating cookies in javascript / jquery

Comment: So.. instead of using native JavaScript, it's easier to import two libraries? Wow